# Fullcalendar slots not coming in full column and starting from middle

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3, fullcalendar-2

I am using full calendar week view with 15 mins of slots.

The slots are not coming as a complete column, and every slot is starting from middle of the row.

In the screen shot the 9am is starting from middle of row instead of starting  How can I achieve that I cant find anything in documentation.

[image]

following is my calendar settings

```
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,

    minTime: "00:00:00",
    maxTime: "24:00:00",

    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    slotLabelInterval: 15,
    slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',

    groupByResource: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek'
    },
    views: {
      agendaWeek: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: { days: 7 }
      }
    },
    resources: [
      { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' }
    ],
    events: [
      {
        title: 'Available',
        start: '2018-09-03T07:30:00',
        end: '2018-09-07T23:00:00',
        color: 'rgba(83,253,173,0.3)'
      },
      { 
        title: 'Booked',
        start: '2018-09-03T09:30:00',
        end: '2018-09-03T10:00:00',
        color: 'rgba(253,83,83,0.3)',
        description: 'This is a cool event'
      },
      { 
        title: 'Buffer Time',
        start: '2018-09-04T09:30:00',
        end: '2018-09-04T10:00:00',
        color: 'rgba(74,74,74,0.5)',
        description: 'This is a cool event'
      },
      { 
        title: 'Rest Time',
        start: '2018-09-05T09:30:00',
        end: '2018-09-05T10:00:00',
        color: 'rgba(240,212,80,0.5)',
        description: 'This is a cool event'
      }
    ]

});
```

Comment: from the screenshot you seem to have deployed some custom CSS to change the appearance of the calendar. This is the most likely place to start looking for problems. Remove it all and use the default CSS provided by fullCalendar and see if you still have an issue.

Comment: BTW the code above does not produce the output shown in the screenshot (disregarding the style changes) - see http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/149/ because you don't have any resource IDs on your events. It really helps on SO questions if the code is accurate.

Comment: If I correct that, then http://jsfiddle.net/qxLuLhsf/151/ shows the events. Annoyingly the events still don't reproduce the screenshot because the event data is different. This is frustrating when trying to reproduce a problem! Please try to create a consistent example in your question. However, you can at least see that there is no issue with the positioning of the events in relation to the time grid. I am 99.99% certain this is an issue with your CSS.

Comment: you are right @ADyson, its becuase of custom css

Comment: Thank you for your consideration

Comment: No problem. If you need specific help in fixing the CSS then of course you could ask a new question about that. Perhaps best to delete this one since it doesn't represent the actual issue.